# Split and run a part of tests on the same browser to run faster

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I have 100 features, i need over 1 hour to run all of them. I want to divide them into 5 groups and run in 5 chrome windows, one group have 20 features. So i can run completely 100 features faster.And number features will always change. How can i control that?

Comment: Use the Selenium Grid with Selenium WebDriver

Comment: Thanks, now i'm using Selenium Grid but I can't dispatch any number of features to per chrome window. Can use tag and group, but i don't want hard set like that, this is so hard to maintain. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424477/how-to-execute-cucumber-test-cases-in-parallel-using-grid), I don't think we can do it without a tag support.

Comment: Do you mean running them on the same browser, but on 5 different tabs? If so, it's not possible. You need to have 1 Chrome browser PER test group.

Comment: @TimothyT. Yes, I want to run 1 chrome browser per test group. But test number of 1 test group is not fixed because the number of all tests will change consecutively. Ex: sum is 100 test -> run 5 chrome with 20 tests/chrome, sum is 300 test -> run 5 chrome with 60 tests/chrome, etc. How does it automatically divide?

Comment: Selenium should be able to handle the test orchestration, which is what you're asking here. Have you setup your Selenium hub + nodes? By sending the test-cases to the hub, it will distribute the test-cases for you in a round-robin manner, depending on the number of nodes you have running.

Comment: @hangamy Running 100 or 300 tests with 5 chromes is possible but can't guarantee the count, I mean 20 tests/chrome instance or 60 tests/chrome instance because the Selenium Hub will take care of distributing the tests to Available Nodes.

Comment: Thank @AliCSE, I understanded